# 404 while connecting to /hello/1 but 200 while connecting to any other number such as /hello/12 in flask

Tags: python, flask

Trying to learn flask but stuck with some error or maybe an issue.

```
def check_int(no):
    return "number is %d" %no
app.add_url_rule('/hello/<int:no>', 'nothign_specific', check_int)
```

So when I do a curl call to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello/1` it fails wherein the same curl call to any other number apart from 1 passes.
`http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello/<any number apart from 1 passes>`

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Aug/2016 14:17:48] "GET /hello/1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Aug/2016 14:18:01] "GET /hello/12 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Can someone let me know what's happening around

Comment: Remove the trailing `/`.

Comment: How it failed with `hello/1` ??

Comment: well tthe thing is irrespective if i type in '1' or '1/' it does not work.
on the other hand if i update the config file with app.add_url_rule('/hello/<int:no>/', 'nothign_specific', check_int)
 it works absolutely fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In flask, if your route (or rule) definition has *no trailing slash* is explicit. If you would add a trailing `/` to your url rule, i.e.

```
'/hello/<int:no>/'
```

then you would be able to use both (request with or without `/`).

According to flask docs, a route with a trailing slash is treated similar to a *folder name in a file system*: If accessed without the slash, flask will recognize it and redirect you to the one with slash. Contrastingly, a route that is defined without a trailing slash is treated like the *pathname of a file*, i.e. it will throw `404` when accessed with a trailing slash.

Read more: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/, section *"Unique URLs / Redirection Behavior"*

Comment: thanks  for getting back, but the thing is when i punch in 1 automatically he trailing line pops in wherein if i punch in anything other than 1 , trailing line does not come at all

Comment: Put a trailing `/` at the end of your rule definition. Do you have any other rules defined under `hello`? What does the log or console output of your application say? Is a redirect triggered if you request `/hello/1` sending you to `/hello/1/`?

Comment: if irrespective of the trailing line given or not, for number 1 automatically it pops up. though its fixed by adding a trailing line on the conf, still confused why not without trailing line